# Hide HTML Range Input Thumb but Keep Tickmarks

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I want to make an HTML range input with the thumb hidden, but I have discrete ticks that I want displayed beneath. Below is example code:

```css
input[type='range'] {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: red;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 5px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: blue;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    width: 0.01px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 0.01px;
    cursor: ew-resize;
    background: black;
    box-shadow: -80px 0 0 80px blue;
}
```

```html
<input
type="range"
min="0"
max="15"
step="0.1"
value=5
className="song-slider"
list="ticks"
/>
<datalist id="ticks">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>15</option>
</datalist>
```

Commenting out line 4 in the CSS (-webkit-appearance) will make the ticks reappear, but also make the thumb reappear. The same happens if I change it to just "appearance: none".

How can I both hide the thumb and keep my ticks shown?

Answer (score -1):

to hide the thumb of the range input while keeping the ticks visible, you can set the width and height of the thumbs to 0, make the background transparent , and remove any box shadow. this will effectively hide the thumb while preserving the visibility of the ticks.

```
input[type='range'] {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: red;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: blue;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none; 
}
```

Comment: You should copy the snippet down here and demonstrate your solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer does not work. You can no longer see the progression of the input as its value changes, and the ticks are still hidden.